# How to specify integers as keys in an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code that grabs some rows from a table and I want to make an associative array in PHP that will be like [row_id] => row_title. This will then be used to populate a select list. The problem is, the key, unless I include a string in it, always reverts to an ordered number starting with 0. If I add a string in with the key, then the key retains the ID that I want. But obviously I don't want the string in the key.

Here's my code:

```
public static function select_array(){
    $courses = ORM::factory('course')->order_by('title')->find_all();
    $out = array();
    foreach($courses as $c){
        $out[$c->id] =  $c->title;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

The $c->id should be the id from the database, but PHP is overriding this with a count number. If I do this:

```
public static function select_array(){
    $courses = ORM::factory('course')->order_by('title')->find_all();
    $out = array();
    foreach($courses as $c){
        $test = "." . $c->id;
        $out[$test] =  $c->title;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Then the key will include the correct ID, but with a "." in front... I've tried using (string)$c->id but no luck with that either. I've also tried setting $test as " " . $c->id and then trimming it, but that doesn't work, and it's just a weird hacky attempt anyway.

Hope that makes sense. My question: How to simply tell the key to be a specific number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you var_dump $courses before the foreach statement and $out before the return?

Comment: After some applied var_dumpage I found the culprit that was messing up the array. 

Indeed, the function as described above works as it should; the keys remain normal ID's from the database. But after this function, I added this:

`array_unshift($courses, "Select course to add");`

At that point, all the keys were reset to an orderly count, beginning with 0 for the unshifted element. Makes sense I guess, but quite interesting that it only happened when all the keys going into array_unshift are integers only!


Thanks to all for the quick response, it helped me keep looking for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's overwriting it, I don't see why.  Try this...

```
foreach($courses as $c){
    $test = "" . $c->id;
    $out[(int)$test] =  $c->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet looks like it should work the way you want. Assuming that $c->id doesn't produce an ordered list of ints, are you sorting the array after retrieving from select_array()?  Have you tried var_dump()'ng $out after the foreach and before the return statement?

If converting to a string solves the problem, try something like

```
$out[(string)$c->id] = $c->title;
```